# Is it possible to get a list of all sockaddr_in addresses for each socket in a multicast group

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, multicast

I am creating a small sender and receiver application which broadcasts its name to all other applications in the multicast group, while also receiving the names of the other applications.

I think I have the sending part done now, as shown below:

```
if (sendto(sock, message, sizeof(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &receiver_addr, sizeof(receiver_addr)) < 0) {
            perror("sendto");
            exit(1);
        }
```

the receiver_addr has its ip address set to the ip address of the multicast group, so I'm sure that each socket in the group has received the message. But now I want to store the received message from each socket in the multicast group, into an array. The example code I've seen uses the following code:

```
if (recvfrom(sock, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sender_addr, &senderlen) < 0)
        {
            perror("recvfrom");
            exit(1);
        }
```

This time the sender_addr variable is the address of the port from which the data came from. But this only gets the information sent by the single host with the address sender_addr. I want to get a list of all addresses of ports inside the multicast group, so that I can run a loop of the recvfrom method, but change the value of receiver_addr to the address of each of the sockets in the group.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to get a list of all sockaddr_in addresses for each socket in a multicast group

No. It isn't even possible to get a list of the members of a multicast group, let alone of any attribute of them.

> the receiver_addr has its ip address set to the ip address of the multicast group, so I'm sure that each socket in the group has received the message.

No you aren't. Multicast runs over UDP, and UDP is an unreliable protocol. You can't be sure of any such thing.

> I want to get a list of all addresses of ports inside the multicast group

Bad luck. You can't.

> so that I can run a loop of the recvfrom method, but change the value of receiver_addr to the address of each of the sockets in the group.

You have a basic misunderstanding of the `address` argument of `recvfrom()`. It isn't a filter that you set beforehand. It is a *result* parameter, telling you from whence the datagram was received.

Comment: is there another approach i can take to collecting data from all the sockets in the multicast group

Comment: Only by getting them all to send you something, e.g. as a signon handshake.